# Java how to get specific point in the future in millis?

Tags: java, android

in my android project I am trying to set an Alarm (using AlarmManager) to notify the user every morning at 7 am and every evening at 7pm to check the app. (It's a todolist so its basically 2 reminders like "Look at your tasks for today" and "Have you done everything").
I got the AlarmManager figured out but after reading some posts here I still can't figure out how to get the correct time.

What I am traing to achieve is the following:

When the user enabled these notifications I want to know what local time we currently have, or better said what hour of the day. if it is less than 7, i want to set the first alarm for today, 7am and the second for today, 7pm.

If it is already past 7 but not 19 yet, I want to set 1 Alarm for today 7pm and the other one for tomorrow, 7am.

If it is past 19 I want to set both alarms for tomorrow at the right time.

The simplest way that works is creating a new Date() and checking it with getHour but pretty much everyone says Date is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

So is there any way of getting a modern Object representing the local time that can a) tell me which hour of the day it is and b) be manipulated so I can get time when I initially want to trigger my Alarm in millis?

EDIT: I already experimented with Instant and OffsetDateTime, but it seems like these can't be manipulated to hav a different time and also I can't figure out how to get the time of those objects in millis.

Comment: Why do you think you can't manipulate with `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` etc? Maybe take a look at the documentation for them and the rest of the Java time classes. For example, `Instant` has a `plus` and `toEpochMillis` method.

Comment: check LocalTime https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html
and use isBefore method

Comment: The class you want is called `LocalTime`.  It represents the time of day (ie, hours, minutes, seconds, fractional parts of a second), without specifying the date.

Comment: Try reading this Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html

Answer (score 2):

> In my android project

Android 26+ has an implementation of the modern *java.time* classes. The latest tooling brings most of this functionality to earlier Android through a process of “API desugaring”. If this does not do it for you, see the Java library *ThreeTen-Backport* and its adaptation to Android, [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

> … I still can't figure out how to get the correct time.

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds):

```
Instant.now()
```

Capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone.

```
ZoneID zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ); 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen the current default time machine of your JVM.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )
```

> … When the user enabled these notifications I want to know what local time we currently have

Capture current time-of-day as seen in the current default time zone of your JVM.

```
LocalTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )
```

> , or better said what hour of the day.

```
int currentHour = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).getHour() ;
```

> if it is less than 7, i want to set the first alarm for today, 7am and the second for today, 7pm.

```
ZoneId zoneId = … ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneID ) ;
LocalTime firstAlarmTime = LocalTime.of( 7 , 0 ) ;    // 7 AM
LocalTime secondAlarmTime = LocalTime.of( 19 , 0 ) ;  // 7 PM
if( zdtNow.getLocalTime().isBefore( firstAlarmTime ) )
{
    ZonedDateTime zdtAlarm1 = zdtNow.with( firstAlarmTime ) ;
}
if( zdtNow.getLocalTime().isBefore( secondAlarmTime ) )
{
    ZonedDateTime zdtAlarm2 = zdtNow.with( secondAlarmTime ) ;
}
```

> If it is already past 7 but not 19 yet, I want to set 1 Alarm for today 7pm and the other one for tomorrow, 7am.

While I do not know about Android programming in general nor its `AlarmManager` specifically, I suspect a better approach would be for each a background thread that periodically checks for an appropriate alarm being currently scheduled.

> If it is past 19 I want to set both alarms for tomorrow at the right time.

```
if( ! zdtNow.getLocalTime().isBefore( secondAlarmTime ) )
{
    ZonedDateTime zdtAlarm1 = zdtNow.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay( zoneId ).with( firstAlarmTime ) ;
    ZonedDateTime zdtAlarm2 = zdtAlarm1.with( secondAlarmTime ) ;
}
```

> The simplest way that works is creating a new Date() and checking it with getHour but pretty much everyone says Date is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Never use the `Date` or `Calendar` classes. These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> So is there any way of getting a modern Object representing the local time that can a) tell me which hour of the day it is

```
int hour = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).getHour() ;
```

> and b) be manipulated so I can get time when I initially want to trigger my Alarm in millis?

```
long millisecondsUntilAlarm1 = Duration.between( zdtNow.toInstant() , zdtAlarm1.toInstant() ).toMillis() ;
```

> EDIT: I already experimented with Instant and OffsetDateTime, but it seems like these can't be manipulated to hav a different time and also I can't figure out how to get the time of those objects in millis.

You just need to study more. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. These topics with *java.time* have been covered many many times already. And study the [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html), free of charge.

You will not likely need `OffsetDateTime`. That class is mainly used for data exchange with databases via SQL.

Comment: I have tried implementing this and it works like a charm. The timing of the alarms are correct now. I cannot thank you enough for the time you took to answer this question so thoroughly.